# Unique Plural with acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I have the following problem. I am trying to get familiar with the package 'acronym'. My main concern is the definition of a plural. Normally you just add an 's at the end, e.g. with `\acp`.

But how do I get the s to be somewhere else?
For example with Point of Crossover (POC) and points of Crossover. How do I define the plural here and would you abbreviate POC or PsOC?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does any style guide expect such a pluralization? I would say that you always add the plural to the acronym at the end, and we adjust in pronunciation if we were reading it out.  The plural morphology is not ever part of the acronym itself.

Comment: In your opinion, so would also fit POCs or?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Once the acronym/initialism (which is technically what your example is) is created, it operates basically like its own word, and so the plural applies to it as if it were a word, so POCs.  This is how we end up with things like "PIN number" and "ATM machine".